# Simple slider using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement simple slider.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s4suryapal/2PuBR/)

The problem is that if there will be more than two slides than it will works fine. But if there are two slides then it cause a issue.

If there are two slides , and we click on previous arrow then it will works fine but when we click on next arrow image will comes after some time thats not look good.

I want to implement same thing by clicking next arrow as it works with previous arrow.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right:0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

Please help me.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

The difference you get here is :

```
function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};
```

You can remove those '+' and '-' in "left" Option.
It makes the difference

Comment: look at the transition way when clicking next button(Its from left to right)

Comment: i don't want to change the transition

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/2PuBR/1/)**</kbd>

Change your `moveRight` function to

```
function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        right: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('right', '');
    });
};
```

Comment: can you look at the transition way when clicking next button(Its from left to right)

Comment: OP doesn't want to change the transition I guess by his above comment, anyways what are the issues OP face here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the code works this way, but if you're thinking about putting more than two slides, adding one more slide seems to somehow do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/ek9bs/

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
<a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
<a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
<ul>
<li>SLIDE 1</li>
<li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li style="background: #ggg;">SLIDE 3</li>

</ul>  
</div>
```

This of course if the two slides you've provided are just examples and you want to add more in general.